# Android: Glide onStart/onResume bug

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide

I have a weird bug with Glide and i'm not sure what to do about it. Basically I have this function, which loads images from reddit.com/r/earthporn/

newsdata.data.children[position].data.url is a list of urls

```
public void displayImage(final int position) {
        Drawable d = view.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_collections_white_24dp);
        System.out.println(newsData.data.children[position].data.url);
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(newsData.data.children[position].data.url)
                .asBitmap()    
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        displayImage(position + 1); 
                        //todo: make sure we don't run into a index out of bounds.
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .centerCrop()
                .error(d)
                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(view.getImageView()) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                        super.setResource(resource);
                        view.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        wallPaperBitmap = resource;
                        System.out.println(resource);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Android can't load every single image that appears on the subreddit. When that happens, I load the next image down. On a run today, it will load this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh5vO.jpg, call an exception, and then load this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILMAD.jpg

OnCreate, this code will run as expected. It runs, hits the exception, calls displayImages() again and sets the correct Image. (Please, let me know if there's a better way to do this)

OnResume/onStart is where the problem lies. The code will run, hit the exception, place the error drawable, call displayImages again but not change the imageview. setResource(bitmap resource) will also give me the correct bitmap but will not let me update the imageview at all.

Basically, it freezes the imageview to the error drawable, or to a blank white screen if there is no drawable and won't let me change it.

Calling onResume with the following code:

```
 if(wallPaperBitmap != null) {
            view.setImageViewPicture(wallPaperBitmap);
            //view.showButtons();
            System.out.println("bitmap != null");
        }
        else {
            retrieveImage(SubReddit.Earth);
            System.out.println("bitmap = null");
        }
```

Will set the correct picture.

I thought maybe this might be a problem with the cache so I tried using diskcachestrategy.none but that didn't help either. As a last resort, I could probably refresh the screen once setResource is called with the updated bitmap or just use Picasso but I'd rather avoid that.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I'm also getting the error: D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null onStart

Answer (score 0):

Glide may restart failed requests in onStart, which would trigger the failure, then set the error Drawable. To fix this, you should do two things:

1. Always call `clear()` on `View`s and `Target`s before calling setImageResource/setImageDrawable yourself (outside of `onResourceReady`). Calling `clear()` will prevent Glide from managing that `View`/`Target`, which in turn will stop Glide from restarting the loading in onStart.
2. If you ever keep a reference to a resource loaded by Glide (usually a `Bitmap` or a `Drawable`, you need to make sure to null out your reference when the `Target`'s [`onLoadCleared`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/Target.html#onLoadCleared(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) or [`onLoadFailed`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/Target.html#onLoadFailed(java.lang.Exception,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) methods are called. This isn't directly related to this issue, but it's an error in your code above and can lead to weird errors if Glide re-uses the Bitmap while you're referencing it.